# BibTeX: .bst Style is Applied on Bibliography, but not on The Citations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, harvard-style, custom-bib

I'm not a very experienced `LaTeX` used.

### What I Created:

- a `.tex` file using `LyX`
- a `.bib` bibliography using `JabRef`
- also my own suitable `.bst` style for `BibTeX` using `custom-bib`'s
  `makebst`

### `pdflatex`'s Output:

(the `.pdf` file produced by `pdflatex file.tex` - converted to plain text)

```
Meine QuellenangabeLundberg vgl. 2003, 3, direkt vor dem restlichen
Text.

Literatur                           # German for bibilography
    Lundberg, Ulla-Lena (2003). Selbstporträt mit Flügeln. Stuttgart: Klett-
    Cotta.
```

### My Problem:

The bibliography is perfect this way, but the citations in the text aren't acceptable:

```
Text beforeLundberg vgl. 2003, 3 text after
```

But I'd like the citations to be like:

```
Text before (vgl. Lundberg 2003: 3) text after
```

That's the way my `.bst` file styles citations. But it seems like my `.bst` file is applied just on the bibliography, but not on the citations in the text.

#### [Update]

Using `\citep` instead of `\citealt`, my citation `\citep[vgl.][3]{Lundberg}` now look like this:

```
Text before (vgl. Lundberg, 2003, 3) text after
```

How can I replace the `,` before the page number by colon and space (`:`)? (To like like this:)

```
Text before (vgl. Lundberg, 2003: 3) text after
```

### My Question:

How can I get `LaTeX` to **style the citations** in the text as described above? - I want my **`.bst` style** to get applied on my citations too.

Thanks for your ideas, for your answers. - If my question isn't clear this way, please write a comment to inform me about that.

### The Sources:

```
% file.tex
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{file}
Meine Quellenangabe\citealt[vgl.][3]{Lundberg}, direkt vor dem restlichen Text.
\bibliography{file}

\end{document}


% file.bib
@BOOK{Lundberg,
  title = {Selbstporträt mit Flügeln},
  publisher = {Stuttgart: Klett-Cotta},
  year = {2003},
  author = {Ulla-Lena Lundberg},
  timestamp = {2013.01.07}
}


% file.bbl
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
{\catcode`\|=0\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\@=11\catcode`\\=12
|immediate|write|@auxout{\expandafter\ifx\csname
  natexlab\endcsname\relax\gdef\natexlab#1{#1}\fi}}

\harvarditem{Lundberg}{2003}{Lundberg}
Lundberg, Ulla-Lena \harvardyearleft 2003\harvardyearright{}.
\newblock Selbstporträt mit Flügeln.
\newblock Stuttgart: Klett-Cotta.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should use the command `\citep` for these citations (and make sure you have a space before this command).  `\citealt` is `\citet` without the parentheses.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks, that helped me a lot. - But there's still one problem concerning the punctuation, I wrote more about that in the `[Update]` section of my question text. Any idea concerning that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `.bst` file does not control the formatting of citations in the text, it only deals with the formatting of the bibliography.

Now `natbib` provides various citation commands and ways to customise them.  To get citations with brackets use `\citep`.  To adjust the punctuation before the post note from a comma to a colon, you can use the `\setcitestyle` command to adjust the `notesep` via

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
```

Putting this together your `.tex` file becomes (using `plainnat` instead of your unposted `.bst` file):

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
Meine Quellenangabe \citep[vgl.][3]{Lundberg}, direkt vor dem restlichen Text.
\bibliography{file}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: Sample output]